# How do I grow a PaperJS tree without crossed branches, and without it spasming?

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I'm trying to use PaperJS with some physics code to generate a dendrite-y tree shape of about 350 nodes that sprout out of a single "origin" node.

I've been able to get most of the way there by simulating three forces:

1. Springs between each node and its parent
2. Tighter springs between each node and the origin node, to put all the nodes in concentric circles around the origin node. Nodes 1 generation will be 1 unit away from the origin, nodes 2 generations away will be 2 units, etc.
3. Gentle inverted gravity between all nodes to spread them out.

I then add each node with a click of the mouse. It works great for a while, but inevitably two things happen:

1. A node sprouts such that its branch crosses another branch. I need to avoid branches crossing.
2. At about 50 nodes, the origin node starts to vibrate. Adding more nodes exacerbates the condition. Eventually the whole dendrite spasms violently and, after another node or two is added, disappears.

I'm stumped as to how to solve these two problems. Can you advise?

Code can be viewed and run [here](https://codio.com/JonathanHarford/Dendrite/tree/js/force_tests2.js). Just click "Project Index" on the top row.

Comment: can you include your code in a *more straightforward* JS sandbox, e.g [Codepen](http://codepen.io), or [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? Navigating through your online IDE is a tad too much